# Java EE deployment issue

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, ejb, cdi

I'm running into some issues in deploying my Java EE application, and could use some advice.
I have 3 components to deploy:

- Integration layer (Data): POJOs and CDI Beans - JAR file
- Application layer (BL): EJBs, CDI Beans and POJOs - JAR file
- Presentation layer: Servlets and such - WAR file

Optimally, I would like to be able to deploy both the integration and application layer JARs in the same Java EE server, but as separate JARs (since I might want to change the hardware configuration later on and separate them into two different servers on two separate machines).
The problem, is that I'm unable to get the CDI injection from the integration layer JAR to the application layer JAR to work. The server says (and probably rightfully so) that it's impossible to resolve the injections.

So far I came up with these possible solutions:

- Package the two JARs into a single EAR file (maybe throw in the WAR as well ...), and deploy that
- Use JNDI between the different layers (possibly create a CDI producer to do a generic injection based on JNDI names or something like that)
- In the integration layer, make the objects being injected into the application layer (the DAOs) EJBs instead of CDI beans

I don't like either of these solutions (especially the last), since they restrict my future deployment options. The second solution does not restrict me, but it might become tedious at some point (when I accumulate a lot of code).

**Finally, my question is:**
Is there an option I didn't find yet, that would allow me to deploy the two JARs on the same server with the CDI injections working ? Possibly something that would still work if at some point I separate the JARs into different servers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are other options as well.

1. Use a java EE container that supports OSGi as well, and use OSGi interface for your deployment dependencies. At least Websphere, Glassfish, JBoss (with jbosgi installed), Jonas support deploying OSGi bundles. This means your modules should be converted into OSGi bundles.
2. Use a container-specific extension that allows modules to communicate between each other. JBoss as jboss-deployment-structure.xml that you can use to have a dependency to another deployment.
3. Use a server-provided shared classpath for your dependencies. Wouldn't really recommend this.

My vote would go for OSGi.

None of them will work by themselves however if you deploy packages to different servers. A remote technology like remote EJBs, remote JNDI lookups, Spring remoting, HTTP-based api, CORBA or similar is needed between different servers. In Java EE, EJB is the de-facto standard for this, but Spring remoting is not bad either.

---

Update: you added that you use TomEE servers. Indeed TomEE won't support the first two options I mentioned. I would use EJB in that case - the fact that you're using EJBs can be abstracted away from the business layer using an EJB delegate, and you could use EJB (stateless session bean) only for the interface part, leaving your DAOs as POJOs.

Comment: I'm deploying on TomEE servers, and I don't think it supports either of those options. I'm also interested in keeping things as independent of the server choice as possible, in case I change the server later on. I realize that EJBs are the way to do this, my only concern is that the objects moving from my integration layer to my application layer are DAOs, and for some reason it seems wrong to me to make them EJBs. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @eitanfar if you use EJBs for this, it is your interface layer that should be EJBs (stateless session beans, to be exact), not the DAOs themselves! The way I've implemented this is to have an EJB layer for interface -> component service interface -> component service implementation -> internal DAOs. This allows maximum decoupling and separation of concerns that I've needed. Also, for all my EJBs there is a separate EJB delegate that actually is used for lookups, so the fact that EJB lookup is done is invisible to the application layer. EJB delegate can be used as a POJO then.

Comment: I do realize this might be more layering than you want, and of course it is not mandatory to have this many layers.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're suggesting that I add the component service implementation layer (since now I already have the component service interface and internal DAOs). I must admit that it does seem more layering than I originally planned for, but than again, it would provide me with more flexibility, as it will increase decoupling. Moreover it also seems to solve my problem in a clean way, since I'll have all the communication done by EJBs, without exposing the DAOs themselves. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

not sure what your goal is but deploying a war is fine, can even be done manually with these commands:

```
mkdir -p webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib
cp myjar*.jar webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/
```

If your goal is to be able to split them you can use TomEE skinny war feature.

Create a war with a WEB-INF/jars.txt file.

In this jars.txt put one line by dependency/jar. It can be the path to the jar or maven coordinates.

Once setup it will allow you to change jars one by one then simply restart the server. This is great when several teams work on the same binary.

There are some alternative with TomEE but this one has the advantage to be easy to change to a portable one (war).